# Load Testing an database instance

Tags: testing

I need to do some load testing on an Ms Sql Server instance.

I want to test an ms sql server instance with N databases, and then be able to see how the response time changes to how many calls that is being made to different databases in the instance.

So I want to be able to configure amount of databases and the frequency of database calls to the different databases in the instance.

I may even want to be able to set an how many databases of the databases in the instance that will be used, for example 10% should be used at the same time.

How can I manage this in an easy way.

I have today methods for setup the environment (the databases and what will be in them).

But how should I make the calls and log the test times, I think I need one computer with the sql server and at least one computer that creates the load and logs access times

Any tips on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can load test the procedures in database

Option 1

- In SQL Server 2008, Data services - Exposing Stored procedure as webservice
- Load test this web service
- VSTT has good information and articles on web testing, load testing
- Visual Studio Performance Testing Quick Reference Guide (Version 2.0) Published http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edglas/archive/2010/04/13/visual-studio-performance-testing-quick-reference-guide-version-2-0-published.aspx

Option 2

- Try sql server query performance testing tool - SQLQueryStress